# DIV vs table - for information, which is better for storing information on advertising site?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've designed a HTML template that's a DIV with sidebar and headers (with a dropdown); two versions, one with sidebar, one without.

The site is the pure HTML for a used car/vehicles site (although the data will be stored as PHP/MySQL, in any case, that's not as relevant here, since this is focusing on the design part of a model-view controller).

I've started to migrate from HTML table to div elements, or, in some test cases, table within div.

For reference a comparison of the two:

```css
table {
width: 600px;
}
td {
border-spacing:2px;
}
img {
width: 200px;
}

.vehicleinfo123 {
width: 600px;
display: block;
}

.vehicleinfo {
        display:  table;
        width:1020px;
        height: 340px;
        background-color:#eee;
        border:0px solid  #666666;
        border-spacing:5px;/*cellspacing:poor IE support for  this*/
       /* border-collapse:separate;*/
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin: 2em;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.vehicleinfo table, td, p {
color: #333333;
}
.vehicleinfo table, td {
width: 100%;
}
.vehicleinfo-b img {
width: 364px;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
display: table-column;
padding-right: 20px;
}
.vehicleinfocontent {
color: #333333;
display: inline;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 40px;
left: 40px;
width: 650px;
margin-left: 140px;
margin-right: 140px;
}

.vehicleinfo8content li {
display: table-cell;
margin-right: 200px;
list-style-position: outside;

}


.vehicleinfocontent body, p {
margin-right: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
.vehicleinfoheader {
margin-top: -2px;
background-color: white;
width: 100%;
color: red;
border: 0px solid;
}

.vehicleinfoheader td {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    background-color: #225140;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 0px;
```

```html
<div class="vehicleinfo123">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://media.ed.edmunds-media.com/ford/fusion/2014/oem/2014_ford_fusion_sedan_titanium_fq_oem_3_815.jpg"></td>
        <td><h3>2016 FORD FUSION SEL 2.0 ECOBOOST</h3>
        flame red</td>
        <td>POA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://media.ed.edmunds-media.com/oldsmobile/cutlass-ciera/1993/oem/1993_oldsmobile_cutlass-ciera_sedan_sl_fq_oem_1_500.jpg"></td>
        <td><h3>1993 CHEVROLET OLDSMOBILE CUTLASS 3.1 V6</h3>, 4 door sedan, blue</td>
        <td>POA</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

    <div class="vehicleinfo">
    <table class="vehicleinfoheader">
    <tr>
        <td><h3>2021 HONDA CIVIC TOURING 2.0</h3></td>
        <td><h3>POA</h3></td>
    </tr>
</table>
      <div class="vehicleinfo-b"><img src="https://media.ed.edmunds-media.com/honda/civic/2021/oem/2021_honda_civic_sedan_touring_fq_oem_6_815.jpg"></div>
      <div class="vehicleinfo-content">
        <p>Bright red </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

It's a bit crudely done, but this is just to explain things.

In general, if I'm creating a template, which is better when you're dealing with information; table, DIV within table, or as I've been experimenting with, flexbox and grid?

I've got the basics of my site's template design working well, but am looking for advice from professionals before these are even up to a standard for public release.

Comment: Do not use tables for page structure. That style went out of fashion 20 years ago. The most up to date way to do this would be to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan: Just tried using flexbox, and it's working well. One question... how would I convert that second example in my original post to work with tlexbox, the one with the green background and then white in the second div (Honda Civic example)?

Comment: Image of car, description of car, price of car looks like tabular data to me (although it is very badly written in the example)

Comment: @Quentin: Wasn't sure what's the correct thing to use for this sort of project. It is badly written, but this was a compilation of various designs.

Comment: @Quentin arguable, however if anything changes in the layout design it will be a nightmare to maintain. I'd always go with a flexible layout instead of tables, unless it literally is a table of data.

Answer (score -1):

I do not recommend using the table to display data because it is not responsive as well as a div element.

or using the table element as a template is deprecated.

If you are an expert on flexbox and grid systems, using div best choice. If you are familiar with bootstrap you can try [bootstrap fexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/).

While using flexbox if you had a problem, Please [take a screenshot](https://take-screenshot.org/) on your template and share!